# How to get a valid surface needed by createVirtualDisplay(String name, int width, int height, int densityDpi, Surface surface, int flags) to proceed

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, android

I want to create a Virtual Display in my application. For that I need a valid surface to feed to the API

> createVirtualDisplay(String name, int width, int height, int
>   densityDpi, Surface surface, int flags)

I tried using SurfaceView and get surface from it using surfaceholder, but did not seem to work. Can someone suggest me how can I get a valid surface in an application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use createVirtualDisplay api introduced in Api 19 (Kitkat)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821189/how-to-use-createvirtualdisplay-api-introduced-in-api-19-kitkat)

Comment: @MD .. though the requirement is same in that post, it deals with a specific case of using createVirtualDisplay using ImageReader. With this post, I mainly want to know in what ways, I can create a valid surface in my application.